# Overflow in the Stack Overflow Hot Meta Stack Overflow question link

Tags: bug, design

The title describes the problem.

A freehand circle is for the happiness of my peers.

[image]

I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: Ander, are you pointing out the fault with the text overflowing the box, which would be solved with the CSS rule `.grid--cell {overflow-wrap: break-word; min-width: 0;}`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes

Comment: If you edit the question to add the information from my comment, people should be able to see that it is not a duplicate. Or I can do that if you want, as my suggested CSS might break something somewhere else and then I can get the blame for it instead of you :) I guess they just saw the "NET_CERT_blah_blah_blah" and jumped to *that* problem instead.

Comment: Oh, and... problem reproduced in Firefox 68.0.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Oh², [We’re removing “Hot Meta Posts” from Stack Overflow's sidebar for now; moderators now fully control](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator) so I guess it will get a status equivalent to "won't fix" unless a highlighted/promoted/? "Featured on Meta" or "Blog" title melts through the edge of the box.

Comment: @AndrewMorton oh indeed. I guess not relevant anymore

Comment: Never mind, perhaps there will be a similarly long "word" in the "Blog" or "Featured on Meta" sections in the future and we can be smug and tell them "I told you so." :)