# How do mods think we should flag for "Featured" tag

Tags: discussion, flags, community-bulletin, featured-questions

**Note** please don't discuss in here what you think *about* the decision itself. I want this to be about what *we* can do to help the moderators handle requests for [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).

As announced in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator) questions on meta will no longer appear as "Hot Meta Posts" and will instead now require a moderator to tag the question as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). as per Tim Posts comment under the OP:

> as mods now control all featured slots. Flag something to be featured and if they agree, nothing prevents them from doing it.

From what I have gathered this has not been communicated to the mods before hand. And thus haven't had the time to form a response on how *they* feel about it, or think about how *they* think it should be handled.

I respect that mods already have a quite packed schedule just handling the usual flags and other responsibilities they have, and that having forced this extra task on them will require some extra time from them, as well as needing some time to figure out how to handle these flags consistently (if possible).

That's why I would like to hear from moderators (mostly, anyone can chip in with good ideas of course!) how they think "Meta feature requests" should be constructed by a user, to make it easier and more consistent for them to handle.

Here's a few issues I have thought of:

**The question asker flags for featured** This seems to me like a no-brainer. Everyone who wants to raise a topic dear to their heart will want it to get attention. However this may not reflect the interests of others.

**The community puts in these flags** This will reflect what the community wants better, but could lead to some pretty bad flag spam if there's a topic being discussed that a lot of people are engaged in, and all start flagging for the featured tag.

**Moderators look at vote count** Though a good indication of how a post is received, this may not always be apparant. For example a post with alot of votes, but split 50/50 would probably slip through.

And how should we formulate the flag, so that mods can make a quick decisive call?

**should we keep it short and concise** "Would like this to be featured"

**should arguments be given in the flag?** "Featured request: This post is about a highly discussed, topical topic. As can be seen by the 200 comments, 50 answers and 5000 upvotes in just an hour"

<sub>A bit tongue in cheek: maybe we need to state in the question we would like to be featured.</sub>

<sub>Can this be featured so we can determine on a format for featured flagging?</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Just create a custom mod flag explaining why you want the post featured.

This is the latest one:

[What's up with the breakdown in communication between Stack Overflow and the community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387599/whats-up-with-the-breakdown-in-communication-between-stack-overflow-and-the-com)

The flag gave a reason the OP wanted it featured. I saw the flag, asked in our mod room and another mod said yep. There's two other featured posts so it's ok. We will have to manage the featured posts so that there's not too many at once and to allow for burninations etc.

Of course how this is managed is new and [we will need to structure some type of policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387602/creating-a-system-for-featuring-posts-tell-the-mods-what-you-want). In which case we will let the community know, or even better the community can let us know what they want.

Comment: Out of interest, how many posts can be featured at the same time? Or rather, what's the max amount of posts tagged as featured that appear in the sidebar?

Comment: @l4mpi 4 if I understand Shog"s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/287976) properly, and they expire after 30 days

Comment: @l4mpi I don't know the limit, when we had hot posts, we'd restrict it to 3. Now who knows

Comment: @Tensibai yeh I'm not sure if it still holds. Probably does. I guess this is something we all need to work out

Comment: Thank you for your response, Yvette. *we will need to structure some type of policy* I feel like this is an important step aswel (hence me making this post). I'll leave the question as unaswered for now, so other people can keep adding ideas on what they want (without feeling like this is *the* answer already).

Comment: @remy_rm oh yes, this is just what we're doing *right now*. We need to formulate something

Comment: @YvetteColomb from what I understand from Tim's annoucement, they just removed the hot posts from the equation, nothing is said about tweaking the number of featured posts to compensate the lack of hot posts

Comment: We need a `schadenfreude` tag to feature