# Who is the customer for the main site?

Tags: discussion

In my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387158/4032703), I posed the question: who is the customer for the main site?

In light of several recent controversial changes, such as [this one to Hot Meta Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator), I would like to pose the question: who does Stack Exchange as a company regard as their customers for the main site? For example, does Stack Exchange view regular users as a customer? In what ways are they seeking to satisfy the need of their different customers?

**Edit:** Here's the first part of my answer there for context for this question:

> Jeff Attwood lists [4 ways that Stack Exchange makes money](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79448/343810) (mostly, advertising, SO for Teams, and Stack Overflow Jobs). That being said, here's a very central question: who does Stack Exchange regard as the actual customer? Who *should* they regard as the actual customer? Is it high-rep users who generate a of the answers, people who moderate the site to keep it clean, casual readers who look at ads, frequent readers who visit the site a lot [but might see fewer ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)? A few other possibilities that I can think of:
>
> - Companies who buy ad space
> - Companies that post jobs
> - People looking for jobs that use the job site
> - New users and/or infrequent users

Comment: It would be beneficial for you to effectively rewrite this question to mirror the question you pose in your linked answer. There is really good context in that answer and I think you should include it here.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker briefly went over this in a comment of his: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387599/whats-up-with-the-breakdown-in-communication-between-stack-overflow-and-the-com/387614#comment715078_387614 (I'm not calling you out, thought it is related, if it's not, let me know)

Comment: It should also be noted that I don't speak for Stack Overflow ( the company). All statements I give are opinions based on my experience in the world; and I have no experience or background information on Stack Overflow (the company).

Answer (score 26):

I'm going to expound upon several comments I made.  All of the usual disclaimers apply (this is my opinion), and I don't speak for Stack Overflow, the company. I am a community elected moderator.  I have no idea how the company views this, I can only look through my own lens as a small business owner.

As a business, if you do not make money, you will not exist. You need money to pay for employees, product development, hardware, hosting, and for future growth.  You need to make more money than you spend.  For the longest time, Stack Overflow presumably survived off of VC funding while they made bets on certain features.  Q & A, Careers, Documentation, Stack Overflow Enterprise, and now Teams.  Product Development is very expensive, and even more expensive when you're a top 50 site on the internet.  Typical startups and small businesses get to try out ideas on a small crowd without worrying about scale. Stack Overflow has to worry about scale with *everything* they do.

This changes the dynamics of the customer quite a bit.

Stack Overflow makes money through Ads, Teams, and Careers, and some money from VCs.  I can't say what the split on any of that is; nor would I try.  If Crunchbase is to be believed, they've raised 68Million in venture capital.  If you believe the average person employed by Stack Overflow costs the company 145K per year, and they've been in business for 10 years and have had 250 employees (conservatively), then they have spent around $362,500,000 on employee costs. That seems a bit high; so I'll knock it down to an average of $100K per employee per year and we'll go with an even $250,000,000 they've spent over 10 years on employee costs.  Now none of that includes server costs; but we'll assume they don't spend any more than [$3 million a year on server costs](https://www.quora.com/How-much-money-does-Wikipedia-cost-on-a-yearly-basis) (to include bandwidth). I feel like I'm being conservative there, but I'm using a number from Wikipedia from 2013; so I'll assume they're in that neighborhood).  More likely the $250,000,000 number is way too high since Stack Overflow didn't have 250 employees for several years; so let's say it's $125,000,000 in costs; and let's say it's $155,000,000 over 10 years to run Stack Overflow.

You and I pay zero dollars for this. There's an old adage if you don't pay for the product you are the product, and that holds true to an extent here as well.  Stack Overflow built up years of leveraging an engaging experience to get eyeballs to ask questions and post answers here, and it's worked.  We are not the customers in the sense that if we stop paying Stack Overflow tomorrow, nothing happens.

We exert some amount of influence, but only in the aggregate.  Due to the [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September), even if the most ardent community voices leave, someone will fill in the gap.  As a micro-example, I stopped posting on Meta for years and nothing happened. There was no discernible side-effect. Others stepped up.

Right now the customer for Stack Overflow (the people who pay them money) are:

- The Ad Networks
- The companies that post jobs
- The companies that purchase the teams product

All of these entities are in some way influenced by our aggregate decisions; but that's only in the aggregate.  "The community" is a stakeholder in Stack Overflow-The-Product's direction, but we aren't the only stakeholder, and if you were to rank the stakeholders, we're probably middle to lower on the list.   This is not a value judgment, just a reality of how money changes hands.

If we were higher on the list of effecting business outcomes (like bringing more money in to the company), then you'd see a more virtuous cycle of business decisions being made off of the community's interactions with Stack Overflow (the company).  Something like: feedback -> change -> more money -> more feedback -> more change -> more money

Personally I wish the direct payment method were doable; I'd happily pay $20 a month for the benefits I receive from Stack Overflow.  However, the economics aren't there; that's why they needed VC funding, and that's why they have ads, and that's why they have to focus on products that will provide them money.  We aren't the customer, we're a stakeholder, we're the generator of the product's value, and we're its target audience; but except for the most extreme of cases we do not affect its bottom line by our actions.

Comment: I enjoyed your answer. Spoken truthfully from a P&L type lens. If the company doesn't make money, we don't have SO - simply put. But I want to add a quick side note in regards to one of the revenue streams - lets take Jobs/Ads. With no consensus of community, no strong coders -> no strong answers -> no point in asking questions -> no questions -> no views -> no platform ->, no ads -> no money -> no SO either way. It's a long chain, but does exist. I foresee a need for SO to re-invest back into the community to keep their revenue streams flowing. I think of it as marketing costs.

Comment: @MattR You're spot on. That's why I spoke about us in the aggregate vs small groups of community members.  If 25% of the answer contributors on the site left, it wouldn't be noticable. If 50% left, it'd be noticable and would have an impact on their bottom line.

Comment: Stack Overflow Premium™ doesn't sound like a bad idea.  Create a version of the site that puts the community as the main stakeholder.

Comment: @KyleWilliamson: wasn't there already an Experts-Exchange site, one with this sort of model and that went bankrupt in 2001. It has been resurrected, I believe, but as a shadow of its former self.