# Did the newest rolled out Featured bugged?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, community-bulletin

[image]

At the moment this post was posted 3 featured question has been asked. Nevertheless we only got 2 which 1 of them wasn't tagged as featured.

**Question:**

1. Is the new featured which replacing HMP limitted to only 2 questions?
2. Intended bug?

Comment: There is a limit of how many posts appear, I believe. Also: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: The box is heavily cached, at 3 different layers. It takes time for it to update.

Comment: Look on the main site. There are more posts and there is a maximum to how many things can be shown in that block at any point in time. If the "Featured on MSE" stuff goes away there will be more slots left for "Featured on MSO"

Comment: Also, there are 4-6 slots for *everything*, and it depends on MSE and blog post counts on how many there are available for Meta featured posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's not quite true. Right now there are six things with the newest blog post.

Comment: Ah, yes, the rules are more complex still than I remembered.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you need to get your numbers right: it always has been 6 to 8 ...

Comment: @rene I should really refresh my memory on this. Bottom line: nothing changed as far as the box is concerned; only that hot meta posts no longer are picked automatically.

Comment: This one looks relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/140890. That tells me 4-6 posts; with “featured” pushing from 4 to 6.  We have 2 blog posts now, and 2 featured MSE so only 2 spots left for Meta “featured” posts.

Comment: Which explicitly saying we've got less space to show meta posts?

Comment: Well, right now. It's unlikely that we will always have two featured blogposts *and* two featured MSE posts.