# Revert to Hot Meta Posts

Tags: discussion

I think [We’re removing “Hot Meta Posts” from Stack Overflow's sidebar **for now**; moderators now fully control](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387546/2191572) has gone on long enough and it makes the sidebar look stale.

Can we at least put a "Hot Meta Posts" beneath "Featured on Meta"?

I think this would bring back some feeling of community.

Comment: It's not happening. And you know it.

Comment: @yivi I had a sneaking suspicion that's the case. I was just hoping that this late and lengthy April Fool's practical joke ran its course given that the title explicitly stated "for now" but I guess it just reveals who the real fool is 

Comment: The problem is that much less posts are advertised now. Breaking a feature without replacing it with something better is...

Comment: This has become more relevant again now that mods no longer have the degree of control they were promised. See: [Has Stack Exchange rescinded moderator access to the featured tag on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392991/798371)

Comment: @WBT Thanks, I did see that post. I must say though, the outlook for the community looks grim...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think the logic is something like this: [about 10% of surveyed people think the community is unwelcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/?cb=1) so we need to get rid of the community.

Comment: @WBT I was just skimming that blog as your comment came in. Can't wait for the question quality metric to hit 92% eventually...