# Has Stack Exchange rescinded moderator access to the featured tag on Meta?

Tags: discussion, moderators, featured-questions, community

[A while ago, Stack Exchange removed "Hot Meta Posts" from Stack Overflow's sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator) (the "Community Bulletin"). To compensate for this algorithmic selection of questions, they gave Stack Overflow moderators the exclusive right to decide what to feature in the sidebar:

> **tl;dr:** We're removing the "Hot Meta Posts" from Stack Overflow's sidebar while we work on looking at how Meta can better meet its goals. To ensure that moderators are able to bring important posts to the community, we'll be giving them exclusive access to the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag. "Featured on Meta" will remain. This only affects Stack Overflow.

[The most recent resignation post by a Stack Overflow moderator, Madara Uchiha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392889/i-am-resigning-as-moderator-on-stack-overflow) was unfeatured just now, after only around 2 days. This was done by a Stack Exchange employee, not by an elected Stack Overflow moderator.

It seems that Stack Exchange staff is now overriding the decisions of community-elected moderators, with respect to [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions.

Have the rules changed here again? Are the Stack Overflow moderators still in control of the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag? Or are there any new rules here in play?

Comment: the post in question was re-featured by a mod 20 minutes after it was removed

Comment: They've never had "exclusive" access to it.

Comment: Hey all, we're talking with Juan about this in the moderator chat room, please hold off on the wild speculation and leaping to conclusions.

Comment: I can understand that a post that essentially announces that two specific persons are fired is problematic from a certain point of view, so I don't have a big issue with the previous decision. A resignation announcement is something entirely different, and there isn't a good justification for this newer action in my opinion.

Comment: this is the [official reply on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342363/383809) – Not anymore. At least for moderator resignation notices.

Comment: So Moderator Resignations are only allowed to be tagged for 24 hours, but when CM/Mods are fired/let go with minimal warning, it's allowed to stay up longer? Shog's farewell has been featured for 3 days now

Comment: It's getting harder and harder **not** to jump to conclusions, when all we are getting is snippets of information, that do not explain anything whatsoever. Every statement made by SE feels like it has some underlying reasoning they are not putting into words leaving us with nothing of substance. They don't seem to have any incentive to communicate any longer.

Comment: I'll be pruning some comments here. Let's continue the discusson in [The Meta Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room), or [Tavern on Meta SE](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), or [Discord](https://discord.gg/tpgZmwR).

Comment: Added this event to the timeline I've been working on: [stackexchange-timeline](https://stackexchange-timeline.webflow.io)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I'm just going to dump an answer in here to keep people somewhat in the loop.

Yesterday Juan posted the following question in our moderator Q&A team:

> How long can moderator resignation posts be featured in the sidebars of our network sites?

Juan self-answered the question with the following:

> Moderator resignation announcements have traditionally been encouraged as opportunities for former teammates to say a goodbye and have others wish them well. They are things we want the community to share in and respond to. Due to recent events however, these resignations have become more and more a place for people to post hurtful words and attack Stack employees, other mods, teammates, and community members.
>
> We still value people posting these when they're stepping away from the team. We also value folks being able to say their goodbyes and we want to continue to feature these resignation posts. However, moving forward we can only allow them to be featured for a day. After that period, we ask that you un-feature the post or ping a CM to do it. The original posts will continue to be a part of Meta but they won't show in the sidebar.

A publicly accessible version of the question was created [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342253/142838), with a [similar but more succinct answer from Juan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342363/142838):

> Moderator resignation posts will be featured for around 24 hours moving forward. We will not remove the posts from Meta but the featured tag needs to be removed after that time.

<sub>The above quotes taken from moderator-only spaces were reproduced here with permission from a CM</sub>

Comment: What is really more humiliating, mods resigning and telling it like it is, or having employees post ridiculous answers they do not believe in?

Comment: There is another aspect to the mod resignation notices that seems to be overlooked in Juan's reply - that is advising the community that there is a change in the moderation of the site.  1 less moderator means fewer people working flag queues, longer times handling flags, etc.

Comment: Is this the only exception to mods controlling featured, or are the CMs coming back on their that only mods control featured, and can un-feature as they seem fit?

Comment: Well, at least we know Stack Exchange Inc. takes a pro-active stance against the negative, unwelcoming vibe that is currently taking hold of the sites.

Comment: I do commend them for being able to spin this into a reason that the community itself is to blame.

Comment: @Sklivvz Option C: a massive public outcry over a policy ostensibly created to improve the company’s image

Comment: @Erik For now, we’re told the policy only relates to moderator resignation notices. So presumably other things can remain featured for longer. But obviously that is subject to change at any time, and I think that writing is on the wall that moderators soon won’t have access to or control over this tag altogether.

Comment: Did we actually loose our minds, increasing value for a company that talks to us like that?

Comment: @CodyGray one wonders then if mods still would be free to post collective "We are dissatisfied with SE management" threads and feature them. Such a thread has been featured and up for 2+ months on money.SE for instance. It's not technically a resignation post...

Comment: @Magisch This has been and is being discussed extensively in private channels with employees, and that thought has already occurred to me. I'm allowing another day to see if clarification and/or an acceptable resolution is incoming; if not, I'll decide what to do from there.

Comment: @CodyGray Seems sensible. I do feel like I have a ton of egg on my face though since just today I was on MSE urging people to try and find a compromise, and later that same day this. Ah well :(

Comment: @Magisch Yes. The egg is starting to become baked on at this point. The major benefit of that 1-day waiting period is that it will give me a chance to cool down a bit. I feel that this is *incredibly* disrespectful to Madara, in particular, but also the entire moderator team and indeed the entire community. A number of us do. I have expressed this view multiple times.

Comment: (gnat melancholically [counting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)) SO currently has a capacity to hold resignation notices featured for 21 days total

Comment: @gnat longer, if each resigning mod first re-features previous posts.

Comment: _to post hurtful words and attack Stack employees, other mods, teammates, and community members_ (taken from the citation of Juan's post here) already is the spin ;) From what I have read so far, might be partly true only for the first group (and only when They deserved it) but not the other three .. generating-truth-by-repeating-untruth seems to be spreading rapidly

Comment: I haven't seen anything hurtful or attacking anybody on Madara's resignation. However, I am glad to the least extent that they allow these posts to be featured for 24 hours.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting pinged by every reply here. If you want to continue the back-and-forth, could you please head over to chat?

Comment: I'll be pruning some comments here. Let's continue the discusson in [The Meta Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room), or [Tavern on Meta SE](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), or [Discord](https://discord.gg/tpgZmwR).

Answer (score 174):

I'm not sure if I am allowed to voice an opinion on this but, can this not become a thing please? Yet another half-baked policy by the overlords that only serves to hide their dirty laundry from plain sight.

Not too long ago, y'all (SE Inc) [decided to remove Hot Meta Posts from the sidebar.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator?noredirect=1&lq=1) Fine, but that meant you then had to put your trust in the moderation team to manage such posts with the featured tag; heck, the question title even says "moderators now fully control"... so what happened to that? Where has that trust gone?

It's been clear for months that the powers that be no longer have any interest in co-ooperating with the community. But "recent events" have shown that this disservice is now being extended to moderators as well. This policy change is so disrespectful, not only to the moderator stepping down, but to the rest of the moderator team. Can the moderators, elected in good faith by the very community that runs your sites, no longer be trusted to do the very job they were instated for? Can you not trust them to ensure that people voice their opinions respectfully?

Nay, they've been doing their job all along. What you see in answers and comments is what remains *after* the mess has been cleaned. What this tells me is two things,

1. that you are expediting the downfall of the community you are "investing" in, and
2. that you can't handle being called out for it.

If you can't take the bad PR, don't make the bad decisions.

Comment: I'm sorry that this post comes across as cynical, but it's been a long day and I've not seen a single pleasant post on this site for a long time.

Comment: *"Where has that trust gone?"* Indeed. And yes, of course you are allowed to voice your opinion on this. I'm going to ensure that you have that right as long as the tools to do so are available to me. If you haven't already, you should review [the discussion about this on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342253/how-long-can-moderator-resignation-notices-be-featured).

Comment: **SO:** [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387546/241211) is the new deal on HMP. **Me:** Uneasy, but let's [try it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387617/241211), and assume good intentions. **SO:** I am altering the deal. Pray I do not alter it further.

Comment: "It's been clear for months that the powers that be no longer have any interest in co-ooperating with the community."  You misspelled "years" there...

Answer (score 91):

This can only mean one thing: It's time for SO mods to step down at the rate of 1 mod per day, so that there can be a continuously featured mod resignation post!

---

The above is of course not quite serious, but not completely in jest either. This latest policy is yet another unneccessary attempt to sweep the existing problems under the rug. At this point, every elected moderator, as well as every user who contributes to SE, must ask themselves: why do you still do free volunteer work for such a company?

I don't think SE will respond seriously to the grievances of the community. The time where this could be resolved with dialogue is long gone, and firing Shog should have driven that point home to everybody. However, if they run out of mods and power users who clean up their sites, they have no choice but to act - either they find new volunteers (hard), or hire people (expensive), or will be overrun by spam and low quality content (bad for ad dollars). So, if you want something to change, I suggest you stop all your moderation and curation activity.

Comment: I saw that some of those resignation posts had bounties on it, effectively promoting the post a bit (not as much as a featured one though). I think there is nothing stopping people from giving bounties to answers they think are worth it... ;)

Comment: @DarkCygnus Not necessarily true. I've been suspended before (albeit not on SO or MSO) for adding a bounty to a question that was controversial. Be careful with adding bounties to questions that put staff in bad light.

Comment: @forest still nothing stopping anybody from putting bounty on any post, technically... if it's a good idea, that's a different thing :0)

Answer (score 25):

I'd propose, that they should introduce a new one meta-tag: [resignation](/questions/tagged/resignation). The amount of resignations so far would justify that. This would also help with not having to keep these excessive hand-made lists up-to-date, when one can simply click the tag.

This is just a pragmatic approach to the sad state of affairs, which would only reflect the given situation.

It would also make sense for archival purposes, so that one has them all in a tag-list and not a manually curated list, eg. so that one can jump from any one of these to the whole listing, as kind of history.

Comment: A tag for this purpose has now been created: [meta-tag:moderator-resignation]

Answer (score 23):

It seems that the rules have indeed changed, and the change follows a pattern that can be observed for some time now - a pattern of detaching the company from the community that helped build it from ground up.

Sadly, I don't expect that this direction will change, since that approach would never be implemented in the first place if the company's bean counters didn't deem it beneficial - for the company of course. For the community - not so much.

Answer (score 11):

While I may have understood the unfeaturing of [In case you missed it: Shog9 and Robert Cartaino are no longer staff members at Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392867/3627607) because of one answer which has been deleted I really don't get the unfeaturing of Madara's resignation notice.

I probably missed comments of the same tone as the answer alluded above under Madara's resignation notice.